# Exchange class loader via command line

Tags: java, classloader

I know that it is possible to replace the class loader by code. Typically you'd create an instance of a class loader in the `main()` method, call `loadClass()` and `invoke()` a method.

**Is it also possible to replace the class loader via a command line option to `java.exe` without modifying the original code?**

I have read about the [-Xbootclasspath](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#i1018570) command line switch which seems to do things like that.

As a first test, I downloaded the source of [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) and compiled it into a JAR file.

I then started my Java program as usual but with the additional `-Xbootclasspath JarClassLoader.jar` switch. I tried all three versions, but all of them give the error message

> Unrecognized option: -Xbootclasspath/a
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: The linked page seems to be specific for JRockit JVM. However, the option is also listed on [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) as a non-standard option for the Java Hotspot VM.